# Arduino only works in root

Tags: root, arduino

I've installed Arduino but as the title says, I can only upload with `sudo`. And yes my user is part of the `dialout` group so that's the weird thing.

Arduino did function before on my system. What could be wrong?

Output `ls -l`:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 apr  2 09:23 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the output of your `ls` command, `/dev/ttyUSB0` and all similart tty device files all belong to `dialout` group.

`crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 apr 2 09:23 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Thus you need to add yourself to that group via `usemod` command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

The change requires logging out and logging back in. This is a very frequent solution and I use it myself for all my development boards that require serial console.

---

Alternative could be setting up a `udev` script that will change ownership of that file whenever it's connected, but changing group for user is preferred approach in a lot of cases

In particular, you should examine output of `dmesg` to obtain the information on vendor and product id of your arduino. Then in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` you could set up `50-arduino.rules` script. For instance, here's example of what I use for Altera's FPGA board:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-usbblaster.rules                                                                              
# USB-Blaster II
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="09fb", ATTR{idProduct}=="*", \
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",MODE="0666"
```

Replace `"09fb"`  with your Arduino's vendor id. `ATTR` part can reman the same. You can run `chown` with `RUN` argument. For instance, use `RUN=+"/path/to/chmod_script.sh root:myuser %k". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14982520/3701431) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i've applied usemod multiple times so i'm stuck. Did i break my ubuntu? I'm not familiar with script so i can't work with it yet. Sorry