# Could not open port /dev/ttyACM0 Error after every restart

Tags: permissions, serial-port, arduino

I'm getting the error could not open port /dev/ttyACM0 : [Error 13] Permission denied : '/dev/ttyACM0 '

To solve this error
I write the coomand 
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0 which solves the problem for that active session only. Once I turn off my NUC or restart the same error is thrown again and again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino only works in root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899374/arduino-only-works-in-root) - use `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
`.

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev` directory is recreated at every boot, so your `chmod` vanishes.

The better way is to determine the group ownership of the device with`ls -l`, then add yourself to that group with `sudo adduser $USER group`

Here's my expanded explanation:

Open a "terminal window" by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-T</kbd>.

Left Click to select this window.

Explore. Type:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0
man ls
```

Fix. Type;

```
sudo adduser $USER $(stat --format="%G" /dev/ttyACM0 )
```

When prompted, type your login password.

This will set things up so that your next (and all subsequent) login will have group access to `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Therefore, logoff, login and be happy.

Comment: I didn't get what you are recommending. Could you please tell me how to do that.  my device username is unity-ubantu